# How to format Jan-2018 i.e how to get the mon-year format in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-format

I'm trying to change the data-type of a column in a pandas dataframe to datetype from string. My required format is Mon-Year (eg: Jan-2018). I have tried:

```
dataframe['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['date_col'], format='%b-%Y')
```

I got the following warning, and the output that I get is in the format year-month-day something like (2018-01-01).

> **main**:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using
>   .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

How to get the output format I want, which is Jan-2018.

Comment: Can you provide the first couple of rows of your data to reproduce this problem? For instance `df.head(5)`.

Comment: usd_applicant_dataset['last_pymnt_d'].head(5)
               Out[25]: 
               0    Jan-2015
               1    Apr-2013
               2    Jun-2014
               3    Jan-2015
               4    Jan-2016
Name: last_pymnt_d, dtype: object, After using 
                                                              
usd_applicant_dataset['last_pymnt_d'] = pd.to_datetime(usd_applicant_dataset['last_pymnt_d'], format = '%b-%Y')Out[24]: 
0   2015-01-01
1   2013-04-01
2   2014-06-01
3   2015-01-01
4   2016-01-01
Name: last_pymnt_d, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: Can you add this data to your question (as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52800107/edit))? Before applying the `pd.to_datetime` and after.

Answer (score 0):

#### `datetime` values are not stored as strings!

They are stored internally as integers and **must** be complete: for example, a `datetime` value must include a day, month and year. You must therefore **choose** one of the following:

1. Store your series with `datetime` dtype and see the *default representation*, i.e. `2018-01-01` when you display or print the series.
2. Store your series with `object` dtype and choose the representation of your choice.

There are **no** "intermediary" options to get the best of both worlds.

**Option 1: `datetime`**

Just use `pd.to_datetime` as you are using it now. Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_col': ['Jan-2018', 'Oct-2018', 'Dec-2018']})

df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], format='%b-%Y')

print(df, df['date_col'].dtype)

    date_col
0 2018-01-01
1 2018-10-01
2 2018-12-01 datetime64[ns]
```

**Option 2: `object`**

Well, this is exactly what you have as your input. Do nothing. Your **input** format `'%b-%Y'` is already in the form `'Jan-2018'`.

#### Note on SettingWithCopyWarning

This warning has nothing to do with `pd.to_datetime`. In all likelihood your `dataframe` is an amiguous slice of another dataframe and therefore Pandas is showing a warning that you may see unexpected results if you do not explicitly copy a dataframe. See also [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)